# Is there any signal generated if we copy/delete a file from Linux folder? How to trap it?

Tags: linux

I am working on a situation in which I need to trap a signal whenever there is a change in a Linux folder. Is any signal generated when we copy/delete/modify the files inside a Linux folder?

I can trap signals like: Ctrl+c , Ctrl+z but am not able to identify if my situation generates a signal.

Answer (score 1):

You need inotify
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw07INotifydth-LX

Comment: OSX has its own file system event http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html

Comment: I have used FSEvents to capture all the events. It is provided by apple itself. Thanks everyone.